# Can you combine sequential testing with the Benjamini-Hochberg/Benjamini-Yekutieli procedure

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, multiple-comparisons, false-discovery-rate, sequential-analysis

I am trying to avoid large amounts of type-1 errors in the evaluation of multiple hypotheses within the same online A/B test. Currently, features are tested across different platforms, with several evaluation metrics each, where every distinct hypothesis is evaluated daily. I already employ sequential testing/alpha spending, but now also want to apply a layer of multiple-hypothesis correction.

My question is, would it be possible to use the alpha generated during sequential testing as the [critical value](https://statisticshowto.com/benjamini-hochberg-procedure) within the Benjamini–Hochberg or Benjamini–Yekutieli procedure? If so, do any specific assumptions apply other than the ones already applying to BH/BY?
There doesn't seem to be any literature on the topic.

Comment: The key problem here is that your different tests will be correlated, both across platforms and over time. [Here is an old thread on multiple comparisons for correlated p-values.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2819/1352) I personally would lean towards analyzing the p-values as panel data themselves and check whether they tend to be below some specific cutoff.